# Docker - Unable to join swarm as manager, able to join as worker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When executing a docker swarm join command (as manager), I face the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = "transport: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match swarm-manager"
```

Joining the same swarm, but as worker, works flawless.

The logfiles show me the following items:

```
kmo@GETSTdock-app01 ~ $ sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/docker.log
time="2018-07-06T09:18:17.890620199+02:00" level=info msg="Listening for connections" addr="[::]:2377" module=node node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy proto=tcp
time="2018-07-06T09:18:17.892234469+02:00" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: { 10.130.223.107:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy
time="2018-07-06T09:18:17.892364019+02:00" level=info msg="waiting 0s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.161362606+02:00" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="cannot create a swarm scoped network when swarm is not active" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy service.id=p3ng4om2m8rl7ygoef18ayohp task.id=weaubf3qj5goctlh2039sjvdg
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.162182077+02:00" level=error msg="fatal task error" error="cannot create a swarm scoped network when swarm is not active" module=node/agent/taskmanager node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy service.id=6sl9y5rcov6htwbyvm504ewh2 task.id=j3foc6rjszuqszj41qyqb6mpe
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.184847516+02:00" level=info msg="Stopping manager" module=node node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.184993569+02:00" level=info msg="Manager shut down" module=node node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.185020917+02:00" level=info msg="shutting down certificate renewal routine" module=node/tls node.id=7j75bmugpf8k2o0onta1yp4zy node.role=swarm-manager
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.185163663+02:00" level=error msg="cluster exited with error: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match swarm-manager\""
time="2018-07-06T09:18:18.185492995+02:00" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.37/swarm/join returned error: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Internal desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match swarm-manager\""
```

I face similar problems when I join as worker, and then attempt to promote the node to a manager node.

Docker version = 18.03.1

OS = Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Anybody an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I would submit this as a docker bug. I've never seen it and I see no one else reporting it. https://github.com/moby/moby/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may or may not work, but you can try

On manager run:

```
docker swarm leave --force
```

Recreate the swarm using:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr [ip-address for initial manager]
```

Then try to add managers using the advertised address

Also you can try:

1. Comment out the proxy from the docker proxy define file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` or `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker_proxy.conf`
2. reload the deamon with
   `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Re-excute  `docker swarm join --token manager`

Comment: Recreating the swarm will probably work, but this is something I would prefer to avoid. Our swarm consists out of 10 nodes, with over 500 services at this moment...

Comment: If you post your qorum

Comment: The only way to get it back is to recreate the swarm

Comment: I had 5 managers, now I only have 4 left, that's also why I want to have it joined as manager again.

Comment: when you run docker nodes

Comment: When you run `docker node ls` do you have a leader?

Comment: Yes I have one.

Comment: The final answer was actually that we needed to disable the proxy server on all existing manager nodes, and the node who was joining as a manager.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to open port `2377` in the joining manager node's firewall; that seemed to do the trick. I'm not sure if this is best practice, as I'm still a noob with Docker Swarm: but add it to the list of things to try if you have this issue.